# Is there a GUI in windows to do CRUD Operations on Oracle Database?

Tags: database, oracle, user-interface, crud

I create my tables using sql developer and I'm looking for a simple GUI to do CRUDs operations instead of script to populate those tables.

Comment: Isn't it one of the goals of the SQL Worksheet in SQL Developer?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle SQL Developer supports GUI for CRUD operations as well as others IDEs.